# send request headers to webserver

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, proxy

in linux, how can i send `GET request headers` to my test-dev web server

im currently working on a vulnerability issue that involves reverse proxy bypass and requires me to change my mod_rewrite pattern rules.

the result below was done by acunetix and i want to simulate the findings and test it.

```
GET @testasp.vulnweb.com/rpb.png HTTP/1.1
Cookie: PHPSESSID=somestrings
Host: 192.167.1.10
Connection: Keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Acunetix-Product: WVS/8.0 (Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner - NORMAL)
Acunetix-Scanning-agreement: Third Party Scanning PROHIBITED
Acunetix-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to just use telnet and paste in the request headers you want to send.  E.g.,

```
$ telnet www.test-dev.tld 80
Trying <some IP>...
Connected to www.test-dev.tld
Escape character is '^]'.
```

This assumes normal HTTP on port 80.  It will just be waiting at this point for input.  Now, just cut-n-paste the headers you want to send...

```
GET @testasp.vulnweb.com/rpb.png HTTP/1.1
Cookie: PHPSESSID=somestrings
Host: 192.167.1.10
Connection: Keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Acunetix-Product: WVS/8.0 (Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner - NORMAL)
Acunetix-Scanning-agreement: Third Party Scanning PROHIBITED
```

and hit return one more time to indicate you've sent all the headers and wait for your response.

If that's too simple for you, there's also Dev HTTP Client in the Chrome App store that gets a bit more sophisticated than this.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. i just want to add this quick. how come telnet could not resolve hostname if im accessing it with sub folder `192.168.1.10/site` but it works okay with `192.168.1.10`.

Comment: telnet takes DNS names or IP addresses only, in the same way that ssh does.  Telnet doesn't speak HTTP, it only make a transport connection, you have to fake HTTP yourself (by typing or pasting in HTTP protocol elements).  I.e., if you want a specific directory on the web server, you'd start with `GET /site HTTP/1.1`